# My Url.createObjectURL/Blob creation of a webworker also creates a failing GET request

Tags: typescript, web-worker

In my code I create Worker from a converted ts file:

```
//woker-builder.js
export default class WorkerBuilder extends Worker {
  constructor(worker: any) {
    super(worker);
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob([`(${code})()`], { type: 'application/javascript' });
    return new Worker(
      /* webpackChunkName: "build-worker" */
      URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    );
  }
}
```

Creating those workers works as expected but they also each create a GET web request to the "url" of `worker.toString()`.

[console output of the networking tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cp2v.png)

I am calling workerbuilder like this:

```
import createColumnChartSeries from '../R2ColumnChart/workers/createColumnChartSeries';
const workerProcess = new WorkerBuilder(createColumnChartSeries)
```

With createColumnChartSeries beeing a (then transpiled) ts file.

workerProcess.onMessage and .postMessage work as expected, but there is this weird GET error described above. I expected to only have the working worker without making any GET requests.

Comment: `super` already calls the parent class `Worker`. You want `return super(
      /* webpackChunkName: "build-worker" */
      URL.createObjectURL(blob),)`

Answer (score 1):

@Kaiido was really close to the answer, thanks!

```
//woker-builder.js
export default class WorkerBuilder extends Worker {
  constructor(worker: any) {
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob([`(${code})()`], { type: 'application/javascript' });
    super(
      /* webpackChunkName: "build-worker" */
      URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    );
  }
}
```

With this call without a return in the body the worker processes get created correctly.